# Cannot delete local worktree branch that is gone

Tags: git, git-branch, git-worktree

I cannot delete local worktree branch that is gone. The keywords are *local*, *worktree branch*, and *gone*. I.e., the question [Cannot delete a Branch that doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982736/) doesn't match with mine.

It happens when I tried to delete the worktree folder before calling `git branch -d`. Observe:

```
MINGW64 /d/Tmp
$ mkdir repoA

MINGW64 /d/Tmp
$ cd repoA

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Tmp/repoA/.git/

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ echo a > a

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ git add .

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ git commit -a -m'added a'
[master (root-commit) 2cff3c3] added a
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ git worktree add -b branch-b ../repoB master
Preparing worktree (new branch 'branch-b')
HEAD is now at 2cff3c3 added a

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ rm -rf ../repoB

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ git branch -d branch-b
error: Cannot delete branch 'branch-b' checked out at 'D:/Tmp/repoB'

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ git branch -d branch-b -f
error: Cannot delete branch 'branch-b' checked out at 'D:/Tmp/repoB'

MINGW64 /d/Tmp/repoA (master)
$ git --version
git version 2.19.1.windows.1
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

`git worktree prune` can remove the worktree, but the `branch-b` is still there:

```
$ git worktree list
D:/Tmp/repoA  2cff3c3 [master]
D:/Tmp/repoB  2cff3c3 [branch-b]

$ git worktree prune

$ git worktree list
D:/Tmp/repoA  2cff3c3 [master]

$ git branch -vv
  branch-b 2cff3c3 added a
* master   2cff3c3 added a
```

How to remove the `branch-b` that I don't want any more?

Comment: You are deleting the directory behind git's back but for git the branch is still checked out. What would you expect it to do? I guess you have to run `git rm repoB` so that it works as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-worktree%5D+delete

Comment: `git worktree prune`

Comment: @phd, thanks! that works. would you like to answer, or I delete this?

Comment: I think the answer at the linked answer is good enough. As for delete — it's up to you.

Comment: Ok. I'll leave it as-is as another entry for people to find the answer. Thx again.

Comment: @phd, new update added to OP. that "[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545293/branch-is-already-checked-out-at-other-location-in-git-worktrees)" doesn't work for my question, please remove. thx.

Comment: `git branch -D branch-b`

Comment: Ah, gotya, thanks @phd!